# Point the right key with a variable of a json array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I get the following json array from an api:

```
response = {"base":"USD","date":"2015-11-05","rates":   
{"AUD":1.3997,"BGN":1.7971,"BRL":3.8008}}
```

I get that from the following http query:

```
$http.get(url).success(function(response){
```

let assume that

```
quote = "AUD";
```

How can I point to the AUD value of rates in response (i.e. rate = 1.3997)?

```
$scope.rate = response.rates.quote;
```

does not work...

Comment: response.rates[quote]; you can use bracket notation to get value through variable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use

```
rates.quote
```

This means that `quote` is a property of `rates` object which is not;

The value of `quote` is the property of  `rates`

Try like this

```
$scope.rate = response.rates[quote];
```

Answer (score 4):

this is called accessing  property value of an object this is how we do it

```js
var quote = 'AUD'
var response = {"base":"USD","date":"2015-11-05","rates":   
{"AUD":1.3997,"BGN":1.7971,"BRL":3.8008}}
object = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))

document.write(object.rates[quote])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those times when you have to use the square bracket notation instead of dot notation even though they are usually interchangeable. You can only use dot notation when you know the real name of the property.  When you are using a variable as a placeholder you have to use square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Dot notaion has its limit, use brackets as others already suggested.

The dot notation is:

> An object property name can be any valid JavaScript string, or anything that can be converted to a string, including the empty string. However, any property name that is not a valid JavaScript identifier (for example, a property name that has a space or a hyphen, or that starts with a number) can only be accessed using the square bracket notation. This notation is also very useful when property names are to be dynamically determined (when the property name is not determined until runtime)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects